# Proof of Howe-Moore Property for $SL(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

On page $210$ of Howe and Tan's Non-Abelian Harmonic Analysis there is the following proposition and proof:

> Let $(\rho, V) $ be a unitary representation of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. The following are equivalent:
>
> (a) weak closure of $\rho(SL(n,\mathbb{R})) = \rho(SL(n,\mathbb{R})) \cup \{0\}$
>
> (b) $ \phi_{u,v}(g) = \langle u, \rho(g) v \rangle $ vanishes at $\infty$ for all $u, v \in V$.
>
> Proof:
> Let $\{\rho(g_n)\}$ be a sequence of operators with $g_n \in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. They are bounded by unitarity. By passing to a subsequence, we can assume that this sequence has a weak limit $T$, that is,
> $$ \phi_{u,v}(g_n) = \langle u, \rho(g_n)v \rangle \to \langle u, Tv \rangle$$ for every $u, v \in V$. This means that $T \neq 0$, if and only if $\phi_{u,v}(g_n) \not\to 0 $ for some $u, v$, and this shows that $(a)$ holds if and only if $(b)$ holds.

This seems to work for showing that $(b)$ implies $(a)$, but the converse is not clear to me. If we assume $0$ is in the weak closure, then we have the existence of a $g_n \to \infty$ such that $\phi_{u,v}(g_n) \to 0$ for every $u, v$, but we need to show that this holds for any $g_n$ which goes to $\infty$.

Comment: what does mean "vanishes at $\infty$" for all $u,v$ ? and [$\rho(g)$ is an unitary operator of some Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_representation), right ?

Comment: A sequence $g_n$ in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ goes to $\infty$ if it has no accumulation points in the space, and we say a function vanishes at $\infty$ if for any sequence $g_n \to \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(g_n) = 0$. The matrix coefficients $\phi_{u,v}$ are what we want to vanish at $\infty$. $\rho(g)$ will always be a unitary operator, but it is still possible for a sequence of unitaries to converge weakly to $0$.

Comment: ok, let's suppose there exists such a sequence of operator, then  b) implies a), while a) implies there exists such a sequence of operator by definition of weak-weak convergence for a sequence of operators $V \to V$ which should be : $T_n \to T$ double weakly if for every $u,v \in V$, $\langle u,T_n v \rangle \to \langle u,Tv \rangle$ ?

Comment: for a normed vector space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$, $T_n \in X$ converges $\to T$ weakly iff for every bounded linear form $f \in X \to \mathbb{R}$ : $f(T_n) \to f(T)$. here $X$ is the set of bounded linear maps $H \to H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space, so the bounded linear forms are $T_n \to \langle u,T_n v \rangle$ for some fixed $u,v \in H$ and $ \langle u,T_n v \rangle \to 0$ for every $u,v$ iff $T_n \to 0$ weakly

Comment: Yes, $T_n \to 0$ weakly iff $\langle u, Tv \rangle \to 0$ for every $u, v$.  a) implies there is a sequence $g_n$ such that $\rho(g_n) \to 0$ weakly (and it is not too hard to see that these $g_n$ must go to $\infty$). The part that seems to be missing is why there can't be a different sequence $h_n$ such that $h_n \to \infty$ but $\rho(h_n)$ converges weakly to something (nonzero) in $\rho(SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (which would contradict b)).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found Howe and Tan to be a pretty sketchy text.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove $(a)$ implies $(b)$. Equivalently, we can prove the contrapositive of the statement: If $\phi_{u,v}$ does not vanish at infinity for some $u,v\in V$, then weak closure of $\rho(SL(n,\mathbb R))\neq \rho(SL(n,\mathbb R))\cup \{0\}$. It is enough to show that $0$ is not in the weak closure of $\rho(SL(n,\mathbb R))$.

We know that

> $T \neq 0$, if and only if $\phi_{u,v}(g_n) \not\to 0 $ for some $u,
>  v\in V$.

By assumption, $\phi_{u_0,v_0}$ does not vanish at infinity for some $u_0,v_0\in V$. In other words, $\phi_{u_0,v_0}(g_n) \not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, where $\{g_n\}$ is a sequence which goes to infinity. So $T=0$ is *not* a weak limit of $\{\rho(g_n)\}$. And it is easy to see that if a sequence $\{\rho(g_n)\}$ converges weakly to $0$, we have $g_n\to\infty$. Hence no sequence in $\rho(SL(n,\mathbb R))$ converges weakly to $0$. So $0$ is not in the weak closure.